# MySQL server only send me 300 row per second

Tags: mysql

For a java software i'm actually using a MySQL database (version 8.0). Only with single table, no relation, because I had to import data from a 2003 access database that was very messy. My primary table contains 15 column, and have almost 25k+ rows actually (almost 20 year of data).

But when i want to load all of the data, with a basic `SELECT * FROM myTable` the query take like 1:20 min with a wifi connection and 0:40 with an ethernet connection, and when i look through MySQL Workbench, in the Select per seconds frame, i see that there is 400 Select per Seconds with wifi and 1000 with an ethernet connection.

So i wonder if the problem comes from the database structure, the sevrer configuration, from my request, of from my software.

PS : When i was using a wamp server in localhost the query was done in max 5 seconds

Comment: It's your network connectivity and the computer that receives the data.

Comment: Ok, so how could i fix this problem ? I've not mentioned but the MySQL server run on a Windows server. If i build a windows vm with a wamp server instance could this resolve my prooblem ?

Comment: I don't know how to fix it, you'll have to test yourself. You checked over ethernet and wifi and you concluded that the speed varies. Then you checked with MySQL installed on the computer that queries it, it was even faster. That tells you that network is a bottleneck. Also, selecting 25k records is odd and that's the first thing that stands out as odd. You can try to do what you mentioned, but I've no idea what the hardware is on that PC, what the network connectivity is etc. You'll have to do trial and error.

Comment: ok so i'll try thx. And for the fact of making a 25k+ rows query, i do it once for the first launch, but i admit that i have to make improvement on that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an request problem, i was doing two request at the same time, added to a network issue, and the solution was a `INNER JOIN`